# Convert GUID to NSString - ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, guid, uuid, endianness

I have defined a `GUID` structure as below

```
typedef struct _GUID {
    unsigned long  Data1;
    unsigned short Data2;
    unsigned short Data3;
    unsigned char  Data4[ 8 ];

} GUID;
```

I’m trying to convert it to `NSString`. However, I’m getting the reversed values for the first three `(long, short,short)`. It may be due to the **Big-endian**.

Example:

```
 GUID testGUID = { 0x865f82d0, 0x3303, 0x403d, { 0xbf, 0xcd, 0xeb, 0xb2, 0xde, 0xd9, 0xa0, 0x69 } };
 NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDBytes:(const unsigned char*)&testGUID];
 NSString *uuidString = [uuid UUIDString];
 NSLog(@"%@", uuidString);
```

**Output**:   `D0825F86-0333-3D40-BFCD-EBB2DED9A069`

**Expected**: `865F82D0-3303-403D-BFCD-EBB2DED9A069`

let me know Is there a way to correct this. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: You can use [this family](http://linux.die.net/man/3/endian) of functions to standardize the endianness (you must do it for Data1 2 and 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@borrrden comment fixed the issue.

Here is the solution.

```
GUID testGUID = { 0x865f82d0, 0x3303, 0x403d, { 0xbf, 0xcd, 0xeb, 0xb2, 0xde, 0xd9, 0xa0, 0x69 } };

testGUID.Data1 = NTOHL(testGUID.Data1);
testGUID.Data2 = NTOHS(testGUID.Data2);
testGUID.Data3 = NTOHS(testGUID.Data3);

NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDBytes:(const unsigned char*)&testGUID];
NSString *uuidString = [uuid UUIDString];
NSLog(@"%@", uuidString)
```

Comment: How to convert an NSUuid to Guid?